# How to create input field dynamically in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have a project, and i would want to know how i can to create a inpult field after an event of onClick?

I have that code:

```js
onSubmitCell = event => {
  const newCell = prompt("Please with new URL:");
  const personCurrent = event.target.value;
  axios.patch(`http://localhost:3004/employee/${personCurrent}`, {
      cellphone: newCell
    })
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response.data);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```

**What it do?**
It get the `value` of `alert` and do the `Patch` to update the attribute of the object.

**What do i want ?**
Instead of open an `alert`, i would want that appeared an `input`, and i get the value of this `input` and did the  `Patch`.

Someone would can help me ? Please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `state` for this I am sharing you basic code so you can Implement.

```
class Test extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isPatch: false
    };
  }

  onSubmitCell = event => {
    const newCell = prompt("Please with new URL:");
    this.setState({
      isPatch: true
    });
    const personCurrent = event.target.value;
    axios
      .patch(`http://localhost:3004/employee/${personCurrent}`, {
        cellphone: newCell
      })
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  onChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      patchValue: e.target.value
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {" "}
        {this.state.isPatch && (
          <input
            type="text"
            onchange={this.onChange}
            value={this.state.patchValue}
          />
        )}{" "}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank very much for your answer, helped me much my brother <3

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using a state.

e.g.

```
constructor(){
   super();
   this.state={
       showInput: false
   }
}
render(){
    return(
        <div>
            {this.state.showInput && <input />}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Instead of `alert` you can change the state to `true`. It'll display the `input`.